# Are there any platforms like Github which allow hosting node apps for free?

Tags: node.js, github, hosting

Github allows us to host static build node apps using gh-pages, and I know Vercel exists for Node apps but is there any alternatives to it which are as big as Github and have no upper limits on traffic as such?

Comment: Heroku is free hosting and it's works fine for small projects.

Comment: There's limit on dynos for it any other?